# how to delete librewolf and epiphany/gnome web from the terminal

Tags: command-line, browser, delete

i'm in ubuntu 22.04 LTS when i thought i found the perfect browser,librewolf
i copied all the code from the debian install lines you should put in the terminal and executed it,it worked but i found gnome web/epiphany and tested it,it would have been my fav browser if it could run every vid on youtube but it can't if there is a way to delete these apps or get epiphany to run all youtube videos and get to all sites(potential issue) please help

this is the code i used to get librewolf,for epiphany i just clicked a download button on the gnome website

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y wget gnupg lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates`
distro=$(if echo " una vanessa focal jammy bullseye vera uma" | grep -q " $(lsb_release -sc) "; then echo $(lsb_release -sc); else echo focal; fi)
wget -O- https://deb.librewolf.net/keyring.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/librewolf.gpg
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources << EOF > /dev/null
Types: deb
URIs: https://deb.librewolf.net
Suites: $distro
Components: main
Architectures: amd64
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/librewolf.gpg
EOF

sudo apt update

sudo apt install librewolf -y
```

Comment: Add all the codes you used to install them with edit to your question to get a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

To remove librewolf (or indeed any package) use `sudo apt remove` or `sudo apt autoremove`.

`sudo apt remove librewolf`

Comment: thanks a lot,i was able to delete both browsers